# Why does this error keep appearing when I try to knit?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I keep getting an error when I try to knit, which never happened before:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'readr' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): namespace 'rlang' 0.4.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.5 is required Excution halted

```
{r, echo=TRUE, include=FALSE}
install.packages('readr',repos='https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/readr_1.3.1.tar.gz')
install.packages('dplyr',repos='https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/dplyr_1.0.0.tar.gz')
install.packages('ggplot2',repos='https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.3.2.tar.gz')
install.packages('tidytext',repos='https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/tidytext_0.2.4.tar.gz')
install.packages('tibble',repos='https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/tibble_3.0.1.tar.gz')
install.packages('gutenbergr',repos='https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/gutenbergr_0.1.5.tar.gz')
install.packages('tidyverse',repos='https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.0.tar.gz')
install.packages('wordcloud',repos='https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/wordcloud_2.6.tar.gz')
install.packages('reshape2',repos='https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/reshape2_1.4.4.tar.gz')
install.packages('tidyr',repos='https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/tidyr_1.1.0.tar.gz')
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidytext)
library(tibble)
library(gutenbergr)
library(tidyverse)
library(wordcloud)
library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)
```

Those are the libraries I'm trying to load and I specified the installation because some people said it solved the issue but it did not. The thing is, it's not a problem with that library in particular. I deleted it to see if the error kept popping up and it did, just with another library. I also uninstalled and installed R again but nothing changed.

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: Which library did you delete, readr or rlang?

Comment: I deleted readr but not in the code I pasted here since the result was the same but with another library in the error instead

Comment: Quit R and delete the rlang __library__ (the folder in your current R program folder). Then start R and reinstall the rlang __package__.

Comment: I did it but it didn't change the result, now it's happening with tibble.